# How to assign permission for creating deployments pools - azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I'm struggling trying to create a deployment pool in Azure Devops.

We are not sure which permission we have to assign in order to be able to create new deployments pools.

Does anyone knows where to assign the permission for create deployment pools?

We are getting this error when trying to create one

> Access denied. user needs Manage permissions to perform the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps Server administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create Deployment pools, you need to contact the **`Project Collection Administrators`** to grant you the **`Administrator`** role on Deployment pools.

[image]

The Administrator role can administer, manage, view and use deployment pools.

[image]